# Physical meaning of Rudin's equation in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Rudin's Functional Analysis, p. 334, Corollary of Theorem 13.10 says

> **Corollary** If $a\in H$ and $b\in H$, the system of equations
>   $$-Tx+y=a$$
>   $$x+T^*y=b$$
>   has a unique solution with $x\in D(T)$ and $y\in D(T^*)$

$T$ is a densely defined closed operator in a Hilbert space $H$ (over ($\mathbb{C}$)).

I wonder if there is a known/common physical interpretation of this. My knowledge on physics is not great, but this skew-symmetric-well-not-quite-ness makes me think there might be something like Hamiltonian and, even though it does not seem Rudin explicitly develops a theory on this equation, the fact that he bothered to put this as a corollary might mean something.

Comment: The "matrix" of the system $\left[\matrix{-T & I\\I & T^*}\right]$ is [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_matrix).

Comment: @A.G. Oh thanks I actually tried to verify that formal calculation first but somehow messed up the sign. Still not sure how to interpret though. I have checked Arnold's mathematical methods of classical mechanics, and sort of familiar with the notion of Hamiltonian, Lagrangian and stuff but not sure how to relate those with this. Maybe I should start with one of the references in the wikipedia page?